# Center Content Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, center, html

I've nearly finished my website here: http://www.divisionforty.com/wall/ and I've come to the final part left is to get this content to center http://www.divisionforty.com/wall/artists/cali-balles/

Here is the code:

```
<?php  get_header(); ?>
 <div class="row">
                <div class="span4">

                    <h2><a href="<?php  the_permalink()   ?>"><?php  the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                    <p>
<?php 

    if ( have_posts() ) :
    while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();
    ?>
    <div <?php  post_class()   ?> id="post-<?php  the_ID(); ?>">
            <?php  the_content(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php 
    endwhile;
    endif;
    ?>      </p>
        </div>
                    <div class="span8" id="thumbnails">
                        <?php  postimage($size=thumbnail, $qty=-1)    ?> 
                    </div>
</div>
<?php  get_footer(); ?>
```

There isn't really any style custom to that page so its basic bootstrap.

Hope someone can help,

Denver

To clarify this is what I'd like centered: [image]

Comment: what exactly do you want centered?  Can you be more specific?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/H6C71sC.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Take off the `max-width:1280px` from your `#wrap div`
2. on your `.row` div set the width to `max-width:1200` and the margin to `margin:0 auto`
3. You could also add `text-align: center;` to your `.row` div so your text is centered.

That should keep your content centered as the page gets smaller. (not quite sure what you were looking for.  This will make sure your header goes all the way across the page while centering the content beneath it.)

Comment: I mean `max-width:1200`

Comment: @Denver please mark an answer as accepted if it answered your question otherwise give feedback on what is not resolved.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a new container class.

```
<div class="container_2">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="span4">
         ...
     </div>   
  </div>
</div>
```

In your css, add this

```
.container_2 {
  width: 1200px;  //you can change this.
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

}

Comment: Doesn't seem to change it

Comment: I checked our your website and saw the update html code, but no css update.  Anyways, I tested it out and it does center your span4 and span8 content.  Your problem is the span8 content, doesn't use the entire width, so it doesn't look like it's working.

Comment: Consider nesting a 4 x span3 for the images inside the span8 so you use the entire width of span8.